# Prove that $O_a$ is an ideal of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring, $A$ a left $R$-module and $a ∈ A.$ Denote
$O_a = \{r ∈ R : ra = 0\}.$
Show that $O_a$ is an ideal of $R.$

We have to check three conditions:

$1. \forall x,y \in O_a,\   x-y \in O_a\\
(x-y)a=xa-ya=0+0=0$

$2.\forall x \in O_a,\ \forall p \in R,\ px \in O_a\\
(px)a=p(xa)=p\cdot 0=0$

How to check remaining condition?

$\forall x \in O_a,\ \forall p \in R,\ xp\in O_a\\$

Comment: Is $R$ commutative?

Comment: @giannispapav It is not mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non commutative $R$ I think (but I'm not 100% sure) that this is not true, for example take

$R=M_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $a=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ then $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\in Ann(a)$ since
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

but $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\not\in Ann(a)$

this means that $Ann(a)$ is a left-ideal in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$